# Relative layout 9-patch displaced

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, nine-patch

Here's my problem
[image: Screenshot on Android]

I would like to position the white arrow on the left to the middle of the layout indicated by the red brackets on the right.

The arrow is a 9-patch image

[image: 9-patch image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ></FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_eyes" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/camera_countdown_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="200sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="@null"
            ></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/camera_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@null"
            ></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/camera_editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="#000000"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >
                    <ImageView 
                        android:id="@+id/camera_editor_preview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/camera_editor_left_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/cam_edit_left_arrow"
                    >
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/camera_editor_btn_ok"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Crop"
                    ></Button>
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/camera_editor_btn_no"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

At the point of the screenshot the RelativeLayout with id "camera_editor" is visible (covering the first 4 RelativeLayouts.)

The "camera_editor" Relative layout contains a vertical LinearLayout. 
The upper part is for displaying an image and the 4 borders for cropping. Its contents are confined in a FrameLayout with layout_weight = 1. 
The lower part is contains 2 buttons. Its contents are confined in a LinearLayout with layout_weight = 5.

The white arrow concerned is the background of a RelativeLayout in the upper FrameLayout. The RelativeLayout is initialized to have layout_height="match_parent" (hopefully the height of the FrameLayout) and gravity left, but the arrow is not appearing at the middle.

P.S. the red bar on top is the Action Bar. Everything happens n a fragment.

The graphic layout high-lighting the left arrow
[image: The graphic layout high-lighting the left arrow]

Positions of all arrows are displaced
[image: showing all 4 displaced arrows]

Comment: and the only question marks i saw were in the xml file...

Comment: @pskink At the point of the screenshot, the only RelativeLayout concerned is the one with id "camera_editor". The first 4 RelativeLayouts are hidden from view (in lower layers), you can ignore them.

Comment: i still dont know what you want to get. i only see many layouts which probably are not needed

Comment: @pskink I want to know why the white arrow "@drawable/cam_edit_left_arrow" (a 9-patch img) is not positioned to the center of its RelativeLayout (indicated by the red curly brackets in the first picture)

Comment: use a hierarchyviewer to see views bounds

Comment: @pskink I've added the graphic layout in the PS section. As you can see the RelativeLayout is positioned correctly but, the 9-batch image (the background of the RelativeLayout) is not stretching correctly to position in the center.

Comment: ok, so post the fyll version with four arrows so that i can check it out

Comment: @pskink the full version is also in the PS section but, I've found the solution... my 9-patch was even X even px. I switched to odd X odd px and now it is stretching as expected with all the arrows positioning at the middle of the LinearLayouts at the four sides

Comment: @pskink I've only placed the images in drawable-mdpi and I ran the app on HTC ONE SV (resolution 800 x 480 pixels 4.3") and HTC Sensation XE (resolution 540 x 960 pixels 4.3"). Do you think that there's anything to do with where the resources was placed?

Answer (score 0):

My 9-patch images were even X even px. I switched them to odd X odd px and now they are stretching as expected with all the arrows positioning at the middle of the LinearLayouts at the four sides.

Even this image is stretching correctly!!!!!

[image: a working odd x odd px 9-patch image]

P.S. I've only placed the images in drawable-mdpi and I ran the app on HTC ONE SV (resolution 800 x 480 pixels 4.3") and HTC Sensation XE (resolution 540 x 960 pixels 4.3"). Do you think that there's anything to do with where the resources were placed?